# How to display original name selected in drop down menu when redirected back to the starting page?

Tags: php, html

I want to return to my original index page and have the drop down menu show the name that was originally selected. Then, I want to select another student and perform the task again.

Currently, I am able to:

1. select student from drop down menu and submit the selected student to another page,
2. update the student's traits and redirect back to original page.

I am able to display the students name in the drop down menu  but when I select a new student the student right above my selection is selected instead.

Code for page 1, with drop down menu

```
 <div>
    <?php
     if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
        session_start();
        $pid = $_SESSION['stu_name_id_select'];
        echo $pid;
       }
     ?>
    <form name = "test" method="POST" action = "">
    <?php
    $select_student= $db->prepare("SELECT stu_name_id FROM students WHERE active = 'Yes' order by stu_name_id");    //sql select query
    $select_student->execute();
    echo "<select name='stu_name_id_select' onChange ='this.form.submit()'><option>Select</option>";   
    while ($result1=$select_student->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       echo "<option value = '".$pid."'";
      //echo "<option value = '".$result1['stu_name_id']."'";
      if (isset($_POST['stu_name_id_select']) && $_POST['stu_name_id_select'] == $result1['stu_name_id'])  echo 'selected="selected"';
         echo ">".$result1['stu_name_id']."</option>";  
         $pid = $resule1['stu_name_id'];
        }
    echo "</select>";       
   ?>
 <input type="submit" value="Add/Edit Records"  onclick="test.action='edit_records.php'; return true;" />
 <input type="submit" value="Add/Edit Accommodations"  onclick="test.action='accommodations.php'; return true;" />
 </form>
 </div>
```

Code for the edit_records page,  where I return the selected student back to the index page.

```
if(!isset($errorMsg)){
  $stmt=$db->prepare("UPDATE learning_skills SET SCS = :fname WHERE stu_name_id = '".$id5."'"); //sql insert query                      
$stmt->bindParam(':fname',$fruit);  //bind parameter
if($stmt->execute()){
  $updateMsg=""; //execute query success message
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
    session_start();}
 $_SESSION['stu_name_id_select']   = $id5;
 header("refresh:1;index.php"); //refresh 1 second and after redirect to index.php page
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `session_start` function must be the first thing sent to the browser or it won't work properly. Yours is not the first thing...

Comment: @Kinglish The echo $pid is displaying the correct name so I think that part it is working. If I remove this line, $pid = $resule1['stu_name_id']; the dropdown menu displays the correct name but then I am unable to select a new student since $pid is not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

You're reassigning `$pid` at the end of the loop instead of the beginning, so each student actually has the PID of the previous student.

Simply move `$pid = $resule1['stu_name_id'];` as the first instruction after the `while` loop start.

```
while ($result1=$select_student->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $pid = $resule1['stu_name_id'];
  echo "<option value = '".$pid."'";
  if (isset($_POST['stu_name_id_select']) && $_POST['stu_name_id_select'] == $result1['stu_name_id'])  echo 'selected="selected"';
  echo ">".$result1['stu_name_id']."</option>";  
}
```

Comment: When I move $pid = $resule1['stu_name_id']; I can select the student's name from the drop down window and the issue of selecting the student right above my selection does not occur but when I return back to index page the selected student's name is no longer displayed in the drop down window and it now displays select.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing this code

```
while ($result1=$select_student->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  echo "<option value = '".$pid."'";
  if (isset($_POST['stu_name_id_select']) && $_POST['stu_name_id_select'] == $result1['stu_name_id'])  echo 'selected="selected"';
  echo ">".$result1['stu_name_id']."</option>";  
  $pid = $result1['stu_name_id'];
}
```

to

```
  foreach ($result1 as $row){
     if(isset($_SESSION['stu_name_id_select']) && $_SESSION['stu_name_id_select'] == $row['stu_name_id'])
            {
            echo "<option selected = 'selected'  value=\"".$_SESSION['stu_name_id_select']."\">".$_SESSION['stu_name_id_select']."</option>";
            $_POST['stu_name_id_select'] = $_SESSION['stu_name_id_select'];
            unset($_SESSION['stu_name_id_select']);}
           else{    
             echo "<option value = '".$row['stu_name_id']."'";
             if (isset($_POST['stu_name_id_select']) && $_POST['stu_name_id_select'] == $row['stu_name_id']) echo 'selected="selected"';
             echo ">".$row['stu_name_id']."</option>";}
    }
```